# iPhone - UITextField inside NavigationController Crashing App when touched

Tags: ios4

I have a problem witha UITextField.

Context:
I have a **UITabBar** Controller with 5 Tabs. Each one has a **NavigationController** with their related ViewController.

First Tab, has a UITable. When a row in the table is touched, the user is sent to the second tab, and a new view is pushed in the **NavigationController**.

This new ViewController has a ***UITextField***. When I touch it, the App Crashes with the message in console:
"-[CALayerArray registerDefaults:]:unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x612f280
***Terminating app due to uncoaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: "-[CALayerArray registerDefaults:]:unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x612f280"

Also I've noticed this ViewController also is not responding to Orientation Change... so I assume is something related to the tree...

Everything was constructed with the **Interface Builder**.

If you have any tip or idea of what can be happening, I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the class name on the 3rd (Identity) inspector tab when you click on the `UITextField` in Interface Builder? That's if you're using XCode 4. If you're using XCode 3 with a separate program called Interface Builder, check the last tab on the right hand side (should be an info icon) and there will be a Class field. Make sure that's grey and reads `UITextField`. If not, delete its contents.

Answer (score 0):

in IB, deleting and adding a new UITextField should do the trick.